# Getting the mean of a row in a matrix subtracted from the a value and put into another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to take get the mean of a row in the matrix and subtract that from a value in that row and put that value into a corresponding matrix.  I've done this with a couple for loops but I want to move away from that code.  I'm an experience programmer who is trying to learn how to do things in Matlab without using for loops.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
A = [ 1 3 5;    mean = 3
      2 5 5;    mean = 4              
      3 4 8; ]; mean = 5             

B = [|B_11-mean| |B_12-mean| |B_13-mean|
     |B_21-mean| |B_22-mean| |B_23-mean|
     |B_31-mean| |B_32-mean| |B_33-mean|];

B = [ 2 0 2;
      2 1 1;
      2 1 3; ];
```

Below is the code that I'm using.  I'm planning to scale to a much bigger dataset so I'd like to make it as efficient as possible.

```
[rows columns] = size(A);
B = zeros(rows, columns);
mean_row = mean(A.');
for j=1:rows
  for i=1:columns
   B(j,i) = abs(A(j, i) - mean_row(1,columns));abs(A(j, i) - mean_row(1,columns));
  end
end
```

I've been doing research on how to do this without for loops and how to create the B matrix more efficiently but I haven't been able to get it right.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
B = abs ( bsxfun (@minus, A, mean(A,2) ) );
```

**Test**

```
>> A = [ 1 3 5; 2 5 5; 3 4 8 ]

A =

   1   3   5
   2   5   5
   3   4   8

>> B = abs ( bsxfun (@minus, A, mean(A,2) ) )

B =

   2   0   2
   2   1   1
   2   1   3
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't return the matrix that I'm looking for.  please see the updated question.

Comment: @user2743 Are you giving the same input as you show in question? I pretty much doubt it, since output at my end it exactly same as desired one. Please check Test in updated answer.

Comment: It's si much fun using [tag:bsxfun]!

Comment: @jkshah - you were totally right.  I guess I've been staring and this too long and didn't notice that.  thanks for the help!